# FIie upload with progress bar in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am unable to get percentage in the component from VueX action file.
It doesn't act like reactive
I have used this article as a guidance
https://serversideup.net/file-upload-progress-indicator-with-axios-and-vuejs/
but still unable to get the result.

Vue Component

```
<progress class="col-md-12" max="100" :value="uploadPercentage"></progress>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
            return {
                files: '',
                uploadPercentage: 0,
            }
        },
}
</script>
```

Action.js

```
AddDocument({ commit }, document) {
        // commit('ADD_ITEM_DOCUMENT', document);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: `/add-file/${document.type}/${document.input_name}/${document.parent_id}`,
                        data: document.file,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                        onUploadProgress:function( progressEvent ) {
                            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total ) * 100 ))
                        }.bind(this)
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        var data ={
                            parent_id:document.parent_id,
                            document : response.data.data,
                        };
                        commit('ADD_ITEM_DOCUMENT', data);
                        resolve(response)
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                        reject(error)
                    })
            }, 2000)
        })
    },
```

Comment: you can't use `this.uploadPercentage` to call up the variable of the component, put your function in methods object of component. But if you use vuex set uploadPercentage state and call it in component.

Comment: Thank you. I used the state and problem solved :)

Comment: great, remember to mark the comment as useful :)

Comment: @FabriceFabiyi it would be more suitable to post it as an answer instead of a comment, that way the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this.uploadPercentage` to call up the variable of the component, put your function in methods object of component. But if you use vuex set uploadPercentage state and call it in component.